# Can't make unicorn server start on CentOS boot

Tags: centos, unicorn, init, init.d

I have an [unicorn init](http://gist.github.com/jaygooby/504875) script in /etc/init.d

I have added description to make it centos-compatible.

It is configured in chkconfig:
`unicorn           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off`

It starts normally if I run `/etc/init.d/unicorn start`

But when i reboot my system, it doesn't work. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the unicorn log file to see what the problem is.  It is possible that not all of the services that unicorn requires have started by the time unicorn is started, which would explain why unicorn starts when started manually, but not when started automatically.  If that is the problem, it should be reflected in the unicorn error log.

Also, check the runlevel with the runlevel command (or who -r) to make sure your system is at the runlevel you think it is.